# Querying a MySQL DataBase from JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am working on a Java project. I want a query for mysql related to admission date having mapping between two modules student and attendance. Here's my code so far:

```
public List<Student> findStudentByDate(String admissionDate) {

   System.out.println("call findStudentMethd******************with this pattern"
        + admissionDate
        + "*********************************************");
   return em.createQuery("select student from Student student where student.admissionDate>='' AND < '' like '" + admissionDate + "'")
            .getResultList();
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please include a copy of your database schema.

Comment: It helps if you ask a question rather than just posting code. Having said that, your SQL makes no sense - have you tried executing it in a query window, rather than from Java?

Comment: Given that your SQL scripts contains very elementary mistakes, your SQL knowledge must be very poor. If that is so, you should not test SQL directly in your Java programs. Run SQL scripts separately, in an environment that allows you to see the immediate feedback: results, errors etc. Consequently, do not bring us your SQL scripts integrated in Java code, please, even more so since you are asking specifically about SQL, not about Java. So, to sum up, 1) test all your SQL in a dedicated SQL tool, before putting it in Java, 2) do not post *irrelevant* code, and 3) *do* post important details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query's fracture resides in the fact that you missed the condition.

You have to mention the column and the value in the WHERE clause.

In other words, **student.admissionDate** >= **admissionDate** and **student.admissionDate** >= **admissionDate**.

Here is how the query should look like (emphasize on the WHERE clause!):

```
  " SELECT student " +
  " FROM Student student " +
  " WHERE student.admissionDate >= '" + admissionDate + "'" +
  " AND   student.admissionDate <  '" + admissionDate + "'"
```